# Is there a gcc equivalent in windows?

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction

Visual studio is ok, but i really hate the fact that you have to go through all the process of project creation just to compile one source file. Is there any compiler in windows that allows compilation directly from directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah, for one there's `cl` (the compiler used by Visual Studio). Any half-decent compiler will have a CLI so any C compiler for Windows from `bcc` to Digital Mars should do the trick.

Answer (score 19):

A gcc equivalent in Windows would be... gcc.

I guess a better answer is [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), which is Minimalist GNU for Windows.

Answer (score 5):

The Visual Studio compiler allows you to compile and link source files from the commandline, just like GCC does. Just open a Visual Studio command prompt, and call `cl` with the appropriate options.

The "GCC for Windows" you want also exists, it's called [MinGW](http://mingw.org/), but you may want the more capable [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: +1 for mentioning opening a Visual Studio command prompt. This will set up the correct paths for you, and allow you to call `cl`, or even to use `nmake`, the Studio version of "make".

Comment: I have Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 Open. When typing "cl [option]", I receive prompt: "cl" is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @Dean you need the Native Commandline tools command prompt (there should be several, one for x86, Win64, ARM, and some cross-compiler combinations too). Make sure you installed the C++ compiler and tools when you installed VS2017. It's not installed by default.

Answer (score 2):

There's `cygwin`, a complete GNU environment that runs on Windows. It includes `gcc`.

Comment: Why suggest a bulldozer to hammer a nail into a wooden board?

Comment: It's a complete Unix emulation layer, and if you compile code on it, it won't run on Windows without Cygwin. It's useful for having Unix command line tools on windows and for initial porting of otherwise unix-only software, but if `cl.exe` works, why not just use the native tools?

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceware.org/cygwin/
or
http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Cygwin](http://sourceware.org/cygwin/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)